# Call server method from img src

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a method that returns a string. I want to call that method from my img src
This is the type of code I want to use. I thought I remember this working before. Since the src is using url to retrieve item from server

```
<td><img src="~/MyController/MyAction/" + @string-parameter /></td>
```

so instead of

```
src="MyController/MyAction/
```

have it be

src="results of my MyAction"

Comment: You are instantiating a _controller_ in a _view_?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `ViewModel` (some class that holds data for the view).

Instantiate it in your controller and set the needed properties. Pass to the view.

Make sure the view is a strongly typed one, using the type of the `ViewModel` as the type of `Model`.

Use the value in the view.

```
// ViewModel
public class MyViewModel
{
  public string ImageSrc { get; set; }
}

// In the controller action:
var vm = new MyViewModel { ImageSrc = @my.GetImageName(smile) };
return View(vm);

// view
@model MyViewModel

<td><img src="@Model.ImageSrc" /></td>
```